# Religious animals

Tags: wordplay, rebus

Since I've been only answering so far, I figured I should try creating some puzzles of my own, too. Please be gentle. :-)

Anyway, here's a rebus-like puzzle, but this time the answers are **single words that are related to religion(s)**.

Everything in the pictures is strictly wordplay, the answers are not related to animals in any way. (The animal theme is there just so that we can get pretty pictures.)

So, here we go:

1: [image: Cartoon insect holding a picket sign]

2: [image: A fluffy hoppy animal only partially within the frame]

3: [image: Drooling bear with vision problems]

4: [image: Person apparently using a kitten as a drug]

5: [image: Two fish arranged in a diagonal cross pattern]

6: [image: A feline composed of polygonal flat pieces]

7: [image: A golden lab nursing her puppies]

Granted, some of these might warrant a "groanworthy" or "isn't that a bit farfetched" tag, but luckily we don't have those. Let's see if you guys can figure these out.

And just to avoid any confusion, let's repeat:

**Each answer will be a single word that is related to religion.**

Comment: To be completely honest, number 6 isn't probably going to make much sense to anyone. It seemed like a good joke at the time, though :-)

Comment: Is it a low polytheistic cat face?

Comment: Ajay, I'm sure you're right (except that you need a double "b") -- but you should probably make that an answer rather than a comment. (For questions like this, it's not unusual to have partial answers.)

Comment: @Gareth I commented because I thought answering just one wouldn't be enough. Anyway, will keep adding to the answer I posted. :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I will add the answers as I figure out

1 (answered by @GarethMcCaughan)

> Protest-ant

2

> Rabbi = Rabbit with the end removed

3

> Salvator, Latin for Saviour = salivator missing an I (eye).
>  (OP originally intended Salvation, with the same logic, but Salvator works too)

4 (Also guessed by @elias moments after I edited in)

> Catholic = cat+holic. He is addicted to snorting cats

5 (answered by @MOehm)

> Codex - Ancient manuscripts related to religion.

6 (answered by @APrough)

> Cathedral - Cat + (poly)hedral

7

> Dogma - it is the principles on which a faith is based

Comment: Pretty sure 1 is a Protest-Ant :-). (Feel free to edit this into your answer.)

Comment: Well done, 1, 2 and 7 are all correct; have an upvote!

Comment: 5 might be crusade

Comment: Why would 5 be crusade? (I keep wanting to make cross+fish into crucifix or crucifixion or something but can't see anything that actually quite works.)

Comment: 4 must be a cat-holic

Comment: @elias I just edited that in! Like 5 seconds before you commented :)

Comment: For anyone interested this is the original Snorting dat cat-caine https://imgur.com/gallery/2z1DgHf for 4.

Comment: No. 5 could be a Cod X or Codex.

Comment: It certainly could :-) You guys are way too good at this.

Comment: I'm not terribly convinced that "codex" is a word that is related to religion in any very strong sense. I mean, sure, some old religious documents are codices, but only because some old documents are codices.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan completely agreed. The only reason a codex brings religion into mind is that at the time of codices, writing was an uncommon skill among the non-religious people, so a lot of the writing was also religious. (Checking the Webster 1913 dictionary, sense 3 of ”codex” used to be ”An ancient manuscript of the Sacred Scriptures or any part of them, especially the New Testament”, so if I’m wrong in including the word here, I’m blaming it on the fact that in 1913 the Internet connectivity was so spotty that I couldn’t post this puzzle then)

Comment: Since more than 3 people have contributed to the answer I am making it a community wiki.

Comment: #6 - cathedral - probably self explanatory

Comment: #3 - catholics? (https://www.fisheaters.com/)

Comment: @TracyCramer - #3 is actually the picture of the bear, which I am going to take a guess signifies a yogi.

Comment: @APrough how does bear imply a yogi? The OP mentioned this is only word play.

Comment: Assuming the #3 is an image of a Teddy bear, it could be **Theodre**

Comment: From what I can guess it is a bear missing an eye. I think OP has carefully edited it out. So we might have to remove the letter `i` from some word and get it.

Comment: yogi = Yogi Bear (Hanna Barbera cartoon), but a yogi is also a member of a specific tradition within Hinduism.

Comment: maybe Yoga yogi+bear

Comment: AjayBrahmakshatriya you are definitely on the right track for 3!  Also, great job on 6, @APrough, I was pretty sure that I had gone too far with my logic of ”eight-faced solid made of polygons can be called octahedral, so a *cat*-faced solid made of polygons..”

Comment: @APrough, yes, a bear is a fish eater and the website I linked to (fisheaters.com) is about the Catholic faith.  I'll keep guessing.

Comment: @TracyCramer - My apologies; I did not see the link.  However, #4 is "catholic" I believe, so I will keep thinking as well.

Comment: The bear is salivating and missing an eye, so he might be the sal(i)vator. I've added that -- at the risk of looking silly, of course.

Comment: Well done! I was thinking more along the lines of ”salivation”, but your answer is as good as mine. Tick coming right up!